# JavaFX Can not change UI from non-Application Thread

Tags: javafx

I read all the similiar thema articles, but I still can not figure out my problem. I use LineChart here, and I want to zoom in/out when I scroll. The code like this:

```
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));      
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
    dataModel.getData("value", "value_tbl");    // get data from specified file

    IViewFactory viewFactory = new LineViewFactory();
    view = viewFactory.create();                // create lineChart view

    view.setData(dataModel.getData("value", "value_tbl"));  // load data into LineChart, here should be XYChart.Series
    this.getCanvas(root).getChildren().addAll(view.getView());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    curStage = stage;

   view.getView().setOnScroll(this.scrollHandler);    // set listener

    stage.show(); 
}
```

and here is the listener:

```
EventHandler<ScrollEvent> scrollHandler = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>(){

    @Override
    public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
        System.out.println("view scroll");

            NumberAxis xAxis = ((LineChartView)view).getXAxis();
            xAxis.setLowerBound(xAxis.getLowerBound() + 10);
            xAxis.setUpperBound(xAxis.getUpperBound() - 10);

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
               curStage.show();
            }

            });
    }

};
```

The log says the program runs into the listener, but there is no change on LineChart.

The start() method and scrollHandler part both in Application. But LineChartView  program is in another package.
So, can anyone help me point out the reason why it doesn't work? Thank you so much!

I have read some similiar code which can work, but there is a big different, all the program all under Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers are run by the JavaFX system on the JavaFX application thread.  So you are on the JavaFX application thread and (as the code you provided does not demonstrate spawning any other thread), all of your logic is running on the JavaFX application thread and you don't need to make use of concurrency utilities to switch logic onto the JavaFX application thread; i.e. the call to [`Platform.runLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) is unnecessary.

If you are not sure what thread you are on, you can always find out by invoking:

```
System.out.println("Current thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

For your code, this will always print "Current thread: JavaFX Application Thread".

As to why your code does not work - it is some reason not related to threading, but to determine it would be advisable to include in your (new) question an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which replicates the issue, complete environment details and full text of any error or stack trace you get.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your advice makes me much much more clear about the whole mechanism. And the problem is I should setAutoRange(false).